# Software installation problem

Tags: installation, software-center, flash

I just installed Ubuntu today and I went to the Ubuntu software center to install Adobe Flash player.

And when the install button is pressed, I received the following message:

> Package dependencies cannot be resolved
>
> This error could be caused by required additional software packages which are missing or not installable. Futhermore there could be a conflict between software packages which are not allowed to be installed at the same time.

Please help me.

Comment: Have you closed all your other programs before open the Software-Center?

Comment: Which Ubuntu version? In terminal, do `sudo apt-get update` work without errors?

Answer (score 0):

OK, if you just installed Ubuntu you have Mozilla Firefox.  Try using the Flash-Aid add on:

https://addons.mozilla.org/en-us/firefox/addon/flash-aid/

Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend you to install ubuntu restricted extras

**ubuntu-restricted-extras** is a software package for the computer operating system Ubuntu that allows the user to install essential software which is not already included due to legal or copyright reasons.

It is a meta-package that installs:

- Support for MP3 and unencrypted DVD playback
- Microsoft TrueType core fonts
- Flash plugin
- codecs for common audio and video files

The ubuntu-restricted-extras is a metapackage and has the following dependencies1:

- flashplugin-installer
- gstreamer0.10-ffmpeg
- gstreamer0.10-fluendo-mp3
- gstreamer0.10-pitfdll
- gstreamer0.10-plugins-bad
- gstreamer0.10-plugins-ugly
- gstreamer0.10-plugins-bad-multiverse
- gstreamer0.10-plugins-ugly-multiverse
- icedtea6-plugin
- libavcodec-extra-52
- libmp4v2-0
- ttf-mscorefonts-installer
- unrar

Install via Ubuntu Software Center

or using terminal

```
sudo apt-get install ubuntu-restricted-extras
```